# d3 maps: how to disable zoom on scrollwheel but retain panning by dragging

Tags: d3.js

d3 has zoom and pan rolled into the zoom behavior.  Is there a way to disable zoom on scrollwheel but retain the ability to pan, i.e. move the map when dragging?

Comment: What have you tried? I'm unsure, but it might be possible to set `d3.event`'s `scale` to `1` [`on("zoom")`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#wiki-on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The zoom behaviour really only provides the framework for what you need for zoom, the handling of the generated events is entirely up to you. You are free to ignore parts of the events, or all of them. In this case, you could simply not use the zoom, e.g. like this.

```
function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")");
  // d3.event.scale is ignored
}
```

Comment: This works great.  The only issue is that I have a click-to-zoom function with my map already (not scrollwheel zoom).  This doesn't interfere with that but when I drag the map after clicking to zoom, it scales out to 1:1 then drags fine.  How can I preserve the zoomed-in scale when dragging? Perhaps I need to open a separate question...

Comment: Just save the current zoom level somewhere and set it with `scale(...)` in that function.

Comment: This is a far more elegant way than what I suggested below, however, I would have thought mu suggestion below would work nicely with your implementation.  I also thought it would be interesting to compare the idea (which are pretty similar) so I've set up [this bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7051484) with Lars's implementation and [this](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7051552) one with mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply constrain the zoom with `zoom.scaleExtent([extent])` and the documentation is [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#wiki-scaleExtent)

Comment: This works but the drag is super laggy.  Not sure if that's because of the function or my implementation.